# Can I ask questions on the biology of my pet?

Tags: support, on-topic, questions

I began asking a question on the biology of my fire-bellied toad regarding skin complexion. The question involved inquiries on melanin intake, certain diet patterns, and the biology/science behind skin complexion in amphibians and reptiles.

Is this okay? It seems like it *may* be more appropriate for a Biology StackExchange site or something, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My initial view is that yes you can, but I think it's best if it is the kind of question that is more of interest from the perspective of a pet owner rather than a biologist. Your sample would seem to have interest to a fellow keeper, but a question on the organization of their internal organs, for example, might be better asked on the biology site.